# Error message when generating code - selenium and python Type Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am receiving the following error message while running my code. is anyone able to help me?

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: BrowsingContextFn().currentWindowGlobal is null
```

Code:
from instapy import InstaPy

session = InstaPy(username = "xx", password = "xx")
session.login()

session.set_relationship_bounds(True, percentage=100)
session.set_do_follow(["golf"], amount=10)

session.end()

full script below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/hello.py", line 8, in <module>
    with smart_run(session):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/instapy/util.py", line 1920, in smart_run
    session.login()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/instapy/instapy.py", line 425, in login
    if not login_user(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/instapy/login_util.py", line 362, in login_user
    dismiss_get_app_offer(browser, logger)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/instapy/login_util.py", line 466, in dismiss_get_app_offer
    offer_loaded = explicit_wait(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/instapy/util.py", line 1784, in explicit_wait
    result = wait.until(condition)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 128, in __call__
    return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 415, in _find_element
    raise e
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 411, in _find_element
    return driver.find_element(*by)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: browsingContextFn().currentWindowGlobal is null
```

Comment: Without any code, all we can tell is that `browsingContextFn().currentWindowGlobal is null` and it shouldn't be :)

Comment: from instapy import InstaPy

session = InstaPy(username = "", password = "")
session.login()

session.set_relationship_bounds(True, percentage=100)
session.set_do_follow(["golf"], amount=10)

session.end()

Answer (score 0):

What I did was:

Go to line 1953 of ".../instapy/util.py" and change "PFL" to "VOEL". Worked for me on Windows 10, python 3.6. I.E, change line

```
explicit_wait(browser, "PFL", [], logger, 10)
```

to

```
explicit_wait(browser, "VOEL", [], logger, 10)
```

and that got it working for me, however you may run into an issue with that "Visible Element" tag and you'll have to define an XPath and element in that empty list to wait for visibility of something on the page. Not ideal.

What someone else had said as well, was to update your GeckoDriver. Ensure it's the latest version, restart your computer, and it worked for them, so also try that.